# How to make records favorites

Tags: javascript, cookies, favorite

I have a list of stores on my website.I want users to make stores their favorite.I am not asking them to login & I am not saving in database.

I want to save store ids in cookie for an year.
I have this code.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
} 



function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i].trim();
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}
```

I want to save each store id and then retrieve them.My questions are

1. Is this good to use Cookie?
2. How to save multiple ids?
3. How to retrieve all ids saved/stored in cookie?
4. DO i need to append it to existing cookie?

This code will give me all cookies,I need to get only store ids i saved in cookie.

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: This has the obvious drawback that the data is only available in that browser instance. People tend to visit from multiple devices these days.

Comment: My favorite should only be visible to me...so no issue for that

Comment: The issue is that if you switch computers, or browse from your phone instead of from your desktop computer, it won't be visible to yourself, either.

Comment: Yes i know...but i do not want to be login...i think there is no other way?